# Ionic large modal detect if keyboard is open

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I would like to increase size of modal but still keep the functionality of full-screen modal when keyboard is open.

I tried to set width with the code below.

```
.modal-xxl .modal-wrapper {
  --width: 94vw;
  --height: 94vh;
}
```

This is working well until I start using some input on modal and keyboard opens. Therefore size of modal remain of 94vw width but I would like modal to be 100% wide as it is in normal behaviour.

I don't find any class that indicate that keyboard is open but I know that should exists. The modal has some border-radius by default but when keyboard is open this default radius disappears (border-radius == 0px).

Does someone know which class indicates that keyboard is open?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a specific css class is applied when the keyboard is opened.

I'm doing something similar in an App where I hide a toolbar when the keyboard is displayed. To detect if the keyboard is visible I'm using the following plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard

Once installed you just need to reference it in your constructor:

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';

constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard) { }
```

And you can use **keyboard.isVisible** property in your html.

I haven't tried this myself but for your use case you could try to apply an ngClass to a wrapper of the modal view (such as ion-app):

```
<ion-app [ngClass]="{'global-keyboard-opened': keyboard.isVisible}">
```

And to change the modal-wrapper css to fullscreen when this class is present.

Comment: This is a possible solution but I am looking for something what ionic already using. Since they already change some display behaviour there should be a way that we can reuse it. Maybe I don't set the modal width the right way or they reference style to some new class (I hope something like keyboard-open)

Comment: Looking through the ionic docs, it seems that they just listen to the window keyboard events (keyboardWillHide, keyboardWillShow ) and act accordingly, i.e: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/e82648bda23760c6173c3bf273725b1977f66295/core/src/components/tab-bar/tab-bar.tsx
I agree, a class like keyboard-open applied somewhere would be nice...

Comment: I implemented the solution above but does not work very well. It looks like they have some other conditions when modal goes to full-screen. I tested on iPad and modal goes to full-screen only at landscape mode but not in portrait. So does anyone know all conditions when modals go to full-screen mode?